# XSLT to copy an XML with change of values

Tags: xml, xslt

We have a xml which needs to be transformed using XSLT. But, we have to add two attributes of a tag and place it in other tag.

In below XML compilation tag with column 'Reusable' has values contrib and max_available. We want addition of these two attributes and want it in the attribute postPosition of compilation tag with column "Usable". Now, we have additional requirement to add on the basis of fac value as well.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<answers user="LST">
    <answer name="compile">
        <output>
            <compilations>
                <compilation column="Usable" fac="123" contrib="0" max_available="0" postPosition="35000">
                </compilation>
                  <compilation column="Usable" fac="456" contrib="0" max_available="0" postPosition="35000">
                </compilation>
                  <compilation column="ReUsable" fac="123" contrib="0" max_available="200" postPosition="300">
                </compilation>
                <compilation column="Reusable" fac="456" contrib="100.00" postPosition="100.00" max_available="200">
                </compilation>
            </compilations>
        </output>
    </answer>
</answers>
```

**Output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <answers>
        <answer name="compile">
            <output>
                <compilations>
                    <compilation column="Usable" fac="123" contrib="0" max_available="0" postPosition="500">
                    </compilation>
                      <compilation column="Usable" fac="456" contrib="0" max_available="0" postPosition="300">
                    </compilation>
                      <compilation column="ReUsable" fac="123" contrib="0" max_available="200" postPosition="300">
                    </compilation>
                    <compilation column="Reusable" fac="456" contrib="100.00" postPosition="100.00" max_available="200">
                    </compilation>
                </compilations>
            </output>
        </answer>
    </answers>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="compilation[@column='Usable']/@postPosition">
    <xsl:attribute name="postPosition" select="format-number(../../compilation[@column='Reusable']/(@contrib + @max_available), '0.00')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes there is only one `compilation` with a 'Reusable' `column` in a `compilations` element.

---

### EDIT:

To do the same thing in **XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="compilation[@column='Usable']/@postPosition">
<xsl:variable name="reusable" select="../../compilation[@column='Reusable']" />
    <xsl:attribute name="postPosition"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($reusable/@contrib + $reusable/@max_available, '0.00')" />
    </xsl:attribute>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This xsl is not working and giving error : javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: "select" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:attribute element!

Comment: **Well, why are you tagging your question as XSLT 2.0, when clearly you are NOT using an XSLT 2.0 processor?!**

Comment: Hi Michael,  I was not sure about the XSLT processor earlier.

Comment: @user1131913 See the edit to my post. Please show more consideration for other people's time.

Comment: It's Working and I will take care with the tags.

Comment: @michaelhor257k, anything on the new change I mentioned in my Question. How to put conditions in XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

Following XSLT will copy the Usable compilation and change the value of the postPosition attribute:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="compilation[@column='Usable']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- copy other attributes first -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@column"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@contrib"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@max_available"/>
            <!-- set the postPosition attribute -->
            <xsl:attribute name="postPosition">
                <xsl:variable name="reusableCompilation" select="../compilation[@column='Reusable']"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="number($reusableCompilation/@contrib)+number($reusableCompilation/@max_available)"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!-- copy all child elements -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- generic template - copy all the rest -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will give you following output with the sumb of both attributes @contrib + @max_available:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<answers>
    <answer name="compile">
        <output>
            <compilations>
                <compilation column="Usable" contrib="0" max_available="0" postPosition="300">
                </compilation>
                <compilation column="Reusable" contrib="100.00" postPosition="100.00" max_available="200">
                </compilation>
            </compilations>
        </output>
    </answer>
</answers>
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but `<!-- copy all attributes -->` would be `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>`.

Comment: I changed the comment to `copy other attributes first`. Because one attribute will not be copied - it will be changed.. Next time you may also change the comment yourself ;-)

Comment: Actually, you *could* have copied all the attributes,  then overwrite the one you want to change. That way you don't need to list them manually + you are more future-proof, in case they add an attribute.

Comment: This xsl is working fine, but if I have an attribute in root node. This is just copying xml without adding the elements.

Comment: Correct. If your input structure is not always complete, then you need to do the XSLT more output based. Please provide some input examples.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<answers user="LST">
    <answer name="compile">
        <output>
            <compilations>
                <compilation column="Usable" contrib="0" max_available="0" postPosition="35000">
                </compilation>
                <compilation column="Reusable" contrib="100.00" postPosition="100.00" max_available="200">
                </compilation>
            </compilations>
        </output>
    </answer>
</answers>

Comment: Hi, added sample xml in Input with attribute name